# SSRS Arrow indicators

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2, indicator, arrows

im looking to add some arrow indicators to compare 2 values within my Matrix. Current week v Last week.

I'm getting confused on where to put my expression which I'm currently using (for a Red arrow going down)

```
=Fields!COUNT_Signed.Value<Fields!COUNT_Signed_lw.Value
```

I have entered this into the Start Expr and have -1 in the End Expr.

all I'm getting is Green arrows going up as I'm also using > for green

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `Fields!COUNT_Signed_lw.Value` as the **Value** and you just need to use `=Fields!COUNT_Signed_lw.Value` as your **END** and -1 as the **START**.

The **START** and **END** values are the range of values to compare the Value with.

In this example, the indicator would be **RED** if **ADMIT** is Between **0** and **33**.

[image]

[MSDN - Indicators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633651.aspx)

Comment: I want to be able to use a red arrow for when the this weeks signed figure is lower than last week signed figure.

Comment: I'm ass**m**ing that `COUNT_Signed` is last week. You would want `Fields!COUNT_Signed.Value` as the **Value** and `Fields!COUNT_Signed_lw.Value` as the RED's **END** with 0 as start (unless you have negative numbers which is unlikely with a Count).